# Command Prompt Search for files in a directory take the name of one random

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Inside a directory `c:\configs` I have files with various extensions including the extension .rac. I need a script for the Windows command prompt  that looks inside `c:\configs` for the names of the files that end with the extension .rac, ignoring other extensions. Then of all the names that end with .rac extension the script must choose a random one and process it with the command `c:\programs\submit.exe namerandom.rac`.

For example, suppose that random .rac file is called `mosaic.rac`, then the script executes the command `c:\programs\submit.exe mosaic.rac`. Of course the `mosaic.ra`c name changes each time the script is runs because it is a random selected from the all the .rac files found.

Anyone have an idea in how to do and that can put example code?

Comment: What about using windows powershell for that ? you can do that in 1 line inside powershell ( run c:\powershell) and do this : PS C:\configs> c:\programs\submit.exe  (Get-ChildItem C:\configs\*.rac | Get-Random).Name

Comment: but I need automatic when the computer boots execute the script. With power shell how can I make to run each time Windows boot without the new to run c:\powershell each time?

Comment: You can setup the script to run at boot using windows scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish that, you may use the following...

Firstly, to get all `.rac` files, use the `dir` command. The `/B` switch specifies to output only a bare file list without any headers nor footers. If you want to search the given directory recursively, add the `/S` switch:

```
dir /B "C:\configs\*.rac"
```

Secondly, you need to count the number of returned `.rac` files. You can use a `for /F` loop (parsing the output of `dir` /B) together with `set /A` for that:

```
set /A COUNT=0
for /F "delims=| eol=|" %%L in (
  'dir /B "C:\configs\*.rac"'
) do (
  set /A COUNT+=1
)
```

Thirdly, you need to compute a random number in the applicable range. The built-in variable `RANDOM` retrieves a random number from `0` to `32767`, so we need a little maths. The result will be a number from `0` to `%COUNT% - 1`:

```
set /A RNDNUM=%RANDOM%%%COUNT
```

Fourthly, you can use another `for /F` loop with the `skip` option to select a random file (we skip the previously calculated number `RNDNUM` of lines).
The `if` statement ensures that no `skip` option is provided in case the random number is `0`.
The `goto` command ensures that only the selected file is passed to `submit.exe`. If you omitted it, every file after the selection would be passed over to `submit.exe` too, one after another:

```
if %RNDNUM% gtr 0 (
  set SKIP=skip=%RNDNUM%
) else (
  set SKIP=
)
for /F "%SKIP% delims=| eol=|" %%L in (
  'dir /B "C:\configs\*.rac"'
) do (
  start "" /WAIT "submit.exe" "%%~L"
  goto :CONTINUE
)
:CONTINUE
```

Put together those parts to get the final script.

Type each command and append `/?` in command prompt to get the respective help text displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set n=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /A-D "*.rac"') do (
set "f=%%a" & set "f[!n!]=!f!" & set /a "n+=1")
set /a c=%random% %% n
echo !f[%c%]!
```

Explanation:

- Line #4: it make a pseudo array in `f` with `n` incremented by 1
- Line #5: it take a random number between 0 and the total count of files called `n` with the help of: `%random%` modulo `n`

In this way, this creates a number of variables automatically according to their position then `%random% %% n` picks one.

You might as well picks some manually like this:

```dos
echo !f[0]! !f[1]! !f[2]! !f[3]! !f[4]! !f[5]! ...
```

Comment: Please do add some detailed comments on each and every step for better understanding.