# Starting random batch file from a certain folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, random, cmd

Problem is this, I have one folder named "abc" with several batch files and they are named like this:

> abc1.bat
>   abc2.bat
>   abc3.bat
>   abc4.bat

and so on...

I need a script that will randomly start one of those batch files when I click it. Script I need will be stored in the same folder by the name "abcRandom.bat" or something similar.

Comment: what is the last number  ? are all the scripts really named `abcX.bat`?

Comment: Sorry if i didnt made it clear...i need to create a batch script named abcRandom.bat,because that is the file i need you guys to do for me.Now,i have my own scripts named 

abc1.bat

abc2.bat

abc3.bat

and so on,and that number is growwing from time to time.so far i have 112 of those files stored in the same folder.I need a script that will randomly select and call just one one of the 112 files.I hope that comes more clear.I used abc letters so it would be easyer for me to explain :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set n=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /A-D "*.bat"') do (
   (echo "%%a" | FIND /I "%~nx0" 1>nul) || (
       set "f=%%a" & set "f[!n!]=!f!" & set /a "n+=1"
   )
)
set /a c=%random% %% n
echo start !f[%c%]!
```

You can get an explanation how it works from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32700063/4070433

Comment: Thanx bro,but this didnt work for me because im missing abcRandom.bat file...That is the one i need you guys for to do :) i doesnt have to be called like that,name isnt important,i can name it anyhow,right?

Comment: I am aware of that,but in youre script you used that abcRandom.bat file that i actualy need from you guys... i dont have it,i need it...NVM,point is to call randomly one abc.x file,x stands for number.

Comment: for some reason it didnt do the trick :( ,i marked the one that helped

Comment: Bro,youre a genious,but i found what was blocking me in youre script...
The last line shouldnt be "echo start !f[%c%]!" but it should be "start !f[%c%]!" :D Please,edit youre post and i will gladly mark it,just remove "echo" from the last line :)

Answer (score 1):

Say 1000 is the number of your abcX.bat files. Then this will do the trick:

```
SET /a rand=%RANDOM%*1000/32768+1
CALL abc%rand%.bat
```

Comment: That's it,thanx mate:D

Comment: now,one more thing... what woould that code look like if it would have more characters,something like "word_abc_OtherWord.bat?

Comment: Just put `%rand%` whereever the numer should be, eg. `word_abc123_OtherWord.bat` will become `word_abc%rand%_OtherWord.bat`.

Comment: This is a whole new problem which requires a different solution. Please post it as a new question and I'll give you the code :-)

Comment: @MichaelS - I think it's your turn now (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780441) :)