# Starting random batch file from a certain folder with different characters

Tags: batch-file

I have one certain folder that contains several .bat files and i need a batch script to randomly start or call one of them.
Example:

a_abc_a.bat

b_abc_a.bat

a_abc_b.bat

b_abc_b.bat

As you can see,all the files are named "abc".Can anyone solve this for me?

Comment: I tryed to mix up these codes that i got on my previous post...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778206/starting-random-batch-file-from-a-certain-folder

Comment: Looks like that referenced post provides the answer!  What's the problem?

Comment: @Ian - no problem, see link to other question

Comment: Paul's script from my previous post works to for this,no problems,solved :D
You guys have been very helpfull,thanx alot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Just insert the correct number of files.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET numberOfFiles=112
SET /a rand=%RANDOM%*%numberOfFiles%/32768+1
SET /a count=1
FOR /R %%f IN (*abc*.bat) DO (
    IF !count!==%rand% (
        CALL %%f
        GOTO BREAK
    )
    SET /a count=!count!+1
)
:BREAK
```

This will work as long as the files to be called randomly have `abc` in ther name aber `.bat` at the end. Remember that your main bat file mustn't have abc in it's name or it might be called amongst the other bat files (possible infinite loop).

Comment: Works like a charm :)
But now i figured Paul's script,and i might use that one because i dont have to limit it on any number of files.

Comment: @SlobodanKovačević I'm gladto have helped you. Accept&upvote appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you :D this was all the help i needed,you guys are good and fast :D